# After I finished installing hue, I found that I couldn't integrate my HDFS. Here are some of my configurations. And problems

Tags: hadoop, hue

After I finished installing hue, I found that I couldn't integrate my HDFS. Here are some of my configurations, and problem:

```
SecurityException: Failed to obtain user group information: org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException: User: root is not allowed to impersonate root (error 403)
```

core-site.xml

[image]

hdfs-site.xml

[image]

hue.ini

[image]

Comment: It seems you must change user to another user than `root`.

Comment: Where should I modify it? Does the root user belong to HDFS or hue? If it belongs to HDFS, do I need to create another user on HDFS? If it belongs to hue, no matter whether it is root or not, it should be accessible as long as it is licensed by HDFS

Comment: Don't use root for Hadoop. Just set a normal user for hadoop.

Comment: So now I just need to create a normal user for HDFS and write the user name to hue, right

Comment: When I started the hue service, I added the user hue. Now what I need to do is to let the user have access to HDFS, right

Comment: If you run hdfs as a user *hue* no need to change permissions if it can access hadfs folders.

Comment: This is actually because when I first started the hue service, I created a user of hue. The default hue belongs to the user of hue, so it is normal that he can't access the HDFS of my root user